# Python: Create new column and row in csv file based on data on another column

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

i have an  output.csv file, a large dataset, with a similar output below:

```
index, url
0, www.example1.com
1,  
2, 
3, www.example2.com
4, www.example3.com
```

I want to add a new column, mail to the csv. I am basically scraping the urls (in the example above row 1 and 2 are empty, no url present) in column2 in output.csv to extract the mails present in the urls. 
So the final output I need should be like

```
 index, url, mail
    0, www.example1.com, example1@gmail.com
    1,  
    2, 
    3, www.example2.com, example2@yahoo.com
    4, www.example3.com, example3@hotmail.com
```

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I know its not the best way but you can help yourself by using pandas library and create something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('output.xlsx')

def split_value(i):
    if type(i) == str:
        url = i.split('.')[1]+"@some_domaine"
    else:
        url = np.nan
    return url

df['mail'] = [split_value(i) for i in df.url.values]

df
**Out[1]:** 
index           url                   mail
0  www.example1.com  example1@some_domaine
1               NaN                    NaN
2               NaN                    NaN
3  www.example2.com  example2@some_domaine
4  www.example3.com  example3@some_domaine

df.to_excel(onemoreoutput.xlsx)
```